# javascript object with array value to simple object

Tags: javascript, object

i have a object as with array as value.

```
{"Name":["Saam Loan"],"HitType":["Sanction"],"ListNumber":["676"],"ListName":["EU"],"Score":["100"],"LastUpdateDate":["2019-10-17T00:00:00"],"IsPerson":["true"],"IsActive":["true"]}
```

How can i convert it to 
{ "Name": "Saam Loan", "HitType": "Sanction" }

any idea

Comment: How about `y={Name: x.Name[0], HitType: x.HitType[0]}`?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const obj = {"Name":["Saam Loan"],"HitType":["Sanction"],"ListNumber":["676"],"ListName":["EU"],"Score":["100"],"LastUpdateDate":["2019-10-17T00:00:00"],"IsPerson":["true"],"IsActive":["true"]}
;

const keyIncludedInDesiredKeys = (key) => ['Name', 'HitType'].includes(key);

const extractedObject = Object.keys(obj).filter(keyIncludedInDesiredKeys).reduce((pr, curr) => ({...pr, [curr]: obj[curr][0]}),{});
```

Answer (score 1):

If all properties are surely in array value, then you could do a simple `for in` loop or `array.reduce`

```
// Test data
let obj = {"Name":["Saam Loan"],"HitType":["Sanction"],"ListNumber":["676"],"ListName":["EU"],"Score":["100"],"LastUpdateDate":["2019-10-17T00:00:00"],"IsPerson":["true"],"IsActive":["true"]};

// array.reduce function
let newObj1 = Object.keys(obj).reduce((accumulator, current) => {
  accumulator[current] = obj[current][0];
  return accumulator;
},{})

// OR for in loop
let newObj2 = {};
for(let key in obj) {
  newObj2[key] = obj[key][0];
}

console.log(newObj1) // {Name: "Saam Loan", HitType: "Sanction", ListNumber: "676", ListName: "EU"…}
console.log(newObj2) // {Name: "Saam Loan", HitType: "Sanction", ListNumber: "676", ListName: "EU"…}
```

Links:

Array.prototype.reduce() - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

for...in - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Answer (score 0):

```
const obj = {"Name":["Saam Loan"],"HitType":["Sanction"],"ListNumber":["676"],"ListName":["EU"],"Score":["100"],"LastUpdateDate":["2019-10-17T00:00:00"],"IsPerson":["true"],"IsActive":["true"]};

const result = Object.entries(obj)
    .reduce((accumulator, [key, [value]]) => ({
        ...accumulator,
        [key]: value
    }), {})
```

This will return an object with every key from the initial obj. You can then select only the ones you need. Or filter first and then create the object.

Answer (score 0):

```
let obj = {"Name":["Saam Loan"],"HitType":["Sanction"],"ListNumber":["676"],"ListName":["EU"],"Score":["100"],"LastUpdateDate":["2019-10-17T00:00:00"],"IsPerson":["true"],"IsActive":["true"]}

let finalAnswer = []

for(let x in obj ) {
   finalAnswer.push({
      [x]: obj[x].toString()
   })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function transform (target) {
    const result = {}
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(target)) {
        result[key] = value[0]
    }
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this straight forward solution :

```js
var obj = {"Name":["Saam Loan"],"HitType":["Sanction"],"ListNumber":["676"],"ListName":["EU"],"Score":["100"],"LastUpdateDate":["2019-10-17T00:00:00"],"IsPerson":["true"],"IsActive":["true"]};

for (const keys of Object.keys(obj)) {
  obj[keys] = obj[keys][0];
}

console.log(obj);
```